# How to remove repititve pattern from an image using FFT

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering, fft

- I have image of skin colour with repetitive pattern (Horizontal White Lines) generated by a scanner that uses a line of sensors to perceive the photo.

  [image: raw image]
  [image: raw image2]
- **My Question** is how to denoise the image effectively using FFT without affecting the quality of the image much, somebody told me that I have to suppress the lines that appears in the magnitude spectrum manually, but I didn't know how to do that, can you please tell me how to do it?
- **My approach** is to use **Fast Fourier Transform(FFT)** to denoise the image channel by channel.
- I have tried HPF, and LPF in Fourier domain, but the results were not good as you can see:

[image: result]

My Code:

```py
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = imread('skin.jpg')

R = img[...,2]
G = img[...,1]
B = img[...,0]

f1 = np.fft.fft2(R)
fshift1 = np.fft.fftshift(f1)
phase_spectrumR = np.angle(fshift1)
magnitude_spectrumR = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift1))

f2 = np.fft.fft2(G)
fshift2 = np.fft.fftshift(f2)
phase_spectrumG = np.angle(fshift2)
magnitude_spectrumG = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift2))

f3 = np.fft.fft2(B)
fshift3 = np.fft.fftshift(f3)
phase_spectrumB = np.angle(fshift3)
magnitude_spectrumB = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift2))

#===============================
# LPF # HPF
magR = np.zeros_like(R) #  = fshift1 # 
magR[magR.shape[0]//4:3*magR.shape[0]//4,
 magR.shape[1]//4:3*magR.shape[1]//4] = np.abs(fshift1[magR.shape[0]//4:3*magR.shape[0]//4,
  magR.shape[1]//4:3*magR.shape[1]//4]) # =0 #
resR = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(magR)))
resR = R - resR
#===============================
magnitude_spectrumR
plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(R, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrumR, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(phase_spectrumR, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Phase Spectrum')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(resR, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Processed')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple and effective linear filtering strategy to remove the horizontal line artifact:

Outline:

1. Estimate the frequency of the distortion by looking for a peak in the image's power spectrum in the vertical dimension. The function [scipy.signal.welch](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html#scipy.signal.welch) is useful for this.
2. Design two filters: a highpass filter with cutoff just below the distortion frequency and a lowpass filter with cutoff near DC. We'll apply the highpass filter vertically and the lowpass filter horizontally to try to isolate the distortion. We'll use [scipy.signal.firwin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html) to design these filters, though there are many ways this could be done.
3. Compute the restored image as "image − (hpf ⊗ lpf) ∗ image".

Code:

```
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d
from scipy.signal import firwin, welch

def remove_lines(image, distortion_freq=None, num_taps=65, eps=0.025):
  """Removes horizontal line artifacts from scanned image.
  Args:
    image: 2D or 3D array.
    distortion_freq: Float, distortion frequency in cycles/pixel, or
      `None` to estimate from spectrum.
    num_taps: Integer, number of filter taps to use in each dimension.
    eps: Small positive param to adjust filters cutoffs (cycles/pixel).
  Returns:
    Denoised image.
  """
  image = np.asarray(image, float)
  if distortion_freq is None:
    distortion_freq = estimate_distortion_freq(image)

  hpf = firwin(num_taps, distortion_freq - eps,
               pass_zero='highpass', fs=1)
  lpf = firwin(num_taps, eps, pass_zero='lowpass', fs=1)
  return image - convolve1d(convolve1d(image, hpf, axis=0), lpf, axis=1)

def estimate_distortion_freq(image, min_frequency=1/25):
  """Estimates distortion frequency as spectral peak in vertical dim."""
  f, pxx = welch(np.reshape(image, (len(image), -1), 'C').sum(axis=1))
  pxx[f < min_frequency] = 0.0
  return f[pxx.argmax()]
```

Examples:

On the portrait image, `estimate_distortion_freq` estimates that the frequency of the distortion is 0.1094 cycles/pixel (period of 9.14 pixels). The transfer function of the filtering "image − (hpf ⊗ lpf) ∗ image" looks like this:

[image: Filter transfer function]

Here is the filtered output from `remove_lines`:

[image: Filtered output on the portrait image]

On the skin image, `estimate_distortion_freq` estimates that the frequency of the distortion is 0.08333 cycles/pixel (period of 12.0 pixels). Filtered output from `remove_lines`:

[image: Filtered output on the skin image]

The distortion is mostly removed on both examples. It isn't perfect: on the portrait image, a couple ripples are still visible near the top and bottom borders, a typical defect when using large filters or Fourier methods. Still, it's a good improvement over the original images.

Comment: @Bilal, sorry, could you clarify about the loss in quality? I admit I am not familiar what makes a good output in this application. You might possibly tune the "0.03" (stopband half width) or other args to `scipy.signal.firwin` to get a bandstop filter that works better. Or if you want, you could perform bandstop filtering in the FFT domain by reducing or zeroing-out FFT bins where the vertical frequency is near 1/12 cycles per pixel.

Comment: In [the example result you shared](https://imgur.com/KlYg98c), the distortion in the input image appears to have a much longer period, 20 pixels or so, vs. the 12-pixel period of the skin image. So the same bandstop filter without adjustment won't be effective. Could you edit your question to include the input image from this second example and more info (if you have any) on where this distortion comes from? This will help me and potentially others to understand what range of distortions are being discussed here and come up with a better solution.

Comment: I added the other photo to the question, thanks for your notes.

Comment: @Bilal, thank you for sharing that portrait image example and updating the question. Based on this, I replaced my answer with a revised strategy which I believe works much better. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem,besides my image size being very large , around (2560 x 3960). The following style solved my problem. If the image looks dark than the orginal image , try to increase the tap size and reduce the eps param

Code :

```html
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d
from scipy.signal import firwin, welch

def remove_lines(image, distortion_freq=**, sampling_frequency=**, num_taps=1201, eps=0.025):  #num_tapes 1201 and eps,looks good and elegant
    """Removes horizontal line artifacts from LIDAR scanned image.
    Args:
        image: 2D or 3D array representing the image.
        distortion_freq: Float, distortion frequency in cycles/pixel, or
            `None` to estimate from spectrum.
        sampling_frequency: Float, sampling frequency in Hz.
        num_taps:  number of filter taps to use in each dimension.
        eps: Small positive param to adjust filters cutoffs (cycles/pixel).
    Returns:
        Denoised image.
    """
    image = np.asarray(image, float)
    if distortion_freq is None:
        distortion_freq = estimate_distortion_freq(image, sampling_frequency)
    hpf = firwin(num_taps, distortion_freq - eps, pass_zero='highpass', fs=sampling_frequency)
    lpf = firwin(num_taps, eps, pass_zero='lowpass', fs=sampling_frequency)
    return image - convolve1d(convolve1d(image, hpf, axis=0), lpf, axis=1)

   
    

# Load the  image 
image_path = './s1.jpg'
large_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Set the distortion rate and sampling frequency
distortion_freq =   # Hz  
sampling_frequency =   # Hz

# Denoise the image
denoised_image = remove_lines(large_image, distortion_freq=distortion_freq, sampling_frequency=sampling_frequency)

# Save the result to a file
output_filename = 'denoised_image.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(output_filename, denoised_image)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34752310)