# Denoise this image of a coin, removing periodic noisy lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

I have a 360x360 image I want to remove lines in it

the portion on it has periodic noisy lines I am working on MATLAB
I tried median filter, but not working how to denoise this image and remove lines?

[image]

I tried this

```
%image 360x360
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(image);
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(image,[]);
horizontalProfile = mean(image);
subplot(2, 2, [2, 4]);
plot(horizontalProfile, 'b-');
grid on;

bottomEnvelope = movmin(horizontalProfile, 10);
upperEnvelope = movmax(horizontalProfile, 10);
deltaGL = mean(upperEnvelope- bottomEnvelope)

hold on;
plot(bottomEnvelope, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 2);
plot(upperEnvelope, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 2);
% Compute midline
midline = (bottomEnvelope + upperEnvelope) / 2;
plot(midline, 'm-', 'LineWidth', 2);
columnsToDim = horizontalProfile > midline;
image(:, columnsToDim) = image(:, columnsToDim) - deltaGL;
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(image, []);
```

[image]

But that did not work better

I've uploaded the image data to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p_9tBG4toPPwQSCweaRgOgK9ONxnTYLM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The main reason you are unlikely to get an answer is becase you are asking for image processing algorithmic expertise, rather than code-issues. But you may be lucky, who knows!

Comment: Would you happen to have a grayscale version of this image? It appears you've got a binary version which is rather noisy - and may be difficult to clean up. In my limited experience, this is an artificial complexity in the problem space which could be fixed simply by using an image representation from higher up in the pipeline.

Comment: @Rohitgupta here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65482958), the only difference is that the noise there is vertical!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for the [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/de/dbc/tutorial_py_fourier_transform.html).

FFT converts an image in the spatial domain to its frequency domain. The frequency domain can be used to smoothen particular noises (vertical lines in your case) in the spatial domain by removing the corresponding high frequency signals. There are tons of sources you can inform yourself about it, so I leave this part to you.

Here is my approach.*

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('coin.png',0)

# get the frequency domain
f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))


# smoothen the vertical lines in the spatial domain =
# remove the high frequency signals (i.e. horizontal lines) in the frequency domain 
rows, cols = img.shape
crow,ccol = rows//2 , cols//2
fshift[crow-5:crow+6, 0:ccol-10] = 0
fshift[crow-5:crow+6, ccol+11:] = 0
magnitude_spectrum_no_vertical = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))


# get the spatial domain back
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
img_back = np.fft.ifft2(f_ishift)
img_back = np.real(img_back)
```

[image: Results]

This is the output image only.

[image: output]

Feel free to play around with different approaches: Applying a gaussian filter before FFT to improve the outcome, masking background and so on.

*: Sorry I have no MATLAB. It should be easy to port my Python script to MATLAB, though.