# Removing Color Banding From Images

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I have this image that has visible horizontal color bandings:

[image]

I've tried many filters to remove the bandings but nearly none of them could completely remove the bandings and Overblurring the image results in loss of detail.

Is there any way to remove the bandings using OpenCV?

Thanks

Comment: what's the resolution of the original sensor? Imho this looks like you have used a 32 or 64 bit sensor and saved or loaded it as a 8 bit. If your input is png or tiff you could check whether displaying it in irfanView or GIMP has no banding. If that's the case you could use opencv's imread parameters to load in full precision instead of (default) loading as 3 channel 8 bit.

Comment: @Micka: the banding has nothing to do with a loss of resolution (by the way, there is nothing like a 32 or 64 bits sensor, 16 true bits being exceptional). 256 gray levels are enough to make the bands imperceptible to the human eye.

Comment: yes sorry, I meant just "more than 8 bit" like even the very old kinect sensor which delivers 13 bit embedded in 16 bit. I though that ToF or Lidar might return higher data-depth depth-maps. If depth maps are represented without enough data-depth you will see banding, like in rendering (z-buffering): https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Z_buffer.svg

Comment: probably you should look into dithering

Comment: Just a guess ... Your `.png` is 621x615 (and 8 bit RGBA). Usually, data from sensors have [at least] an even number of pixels/row and an even number of rows. The geometry seems odd to me. Also, you're show an RGBA image. What was the exact pixel format for the [seemingly] B/W sensor? That is, (e.g.) 13 bits in a 16 bit memory cell (ala Micka). How did you rescale/convert the original B/W pixel [to (e.g.) full range 16 bits]? When I did such a project, I got artefacts if I didn't do this correctly (e.g. with saturation, etc.)

Comment: @Cypher if the pattern is repetitive you can use the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480162)

Comment: @Cypher the other way is to use `FFT`, the horizontal noise will be vertical white lines in Frequency domain, after detecting them you can suppress them (Frequency domain filtering).